# Build app with Tools for Apache Cordova fail

Tags: android, jquery, visual-studio, cordova

I want to use Tools for Apache Cordova on Visual Studio 2015 Community.

But the first time create and build application, I got the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error     Error installing local npm package. EducationTesting    C:\Program
> Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets  287
>
> Error BLD401  Error : BLD00401 : Could not find module 'C:\Users\Mr
> Neo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\app.js'. Please Go to
> Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> Cordova Tools -->
> Clear Cordova Cache and try building again.   EducationTesting        1

How should I do to fix it?

I found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109643/visual-studio-2015-preview-apache-cordova-build-error) but I am unable to find `vs-mda` in my Visual Studio folder.

Thanks for all help!