# Sonnar runner error: 'sonar-runner' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: php, sonarqube-4.5

I have just installed sonnar runner on windows 7 using guidelines from sonarqube.com

I have installed sonnarqube4.5 and sonar-runner on C drive but my project is in xampp/htdocs in D drive.

Now when I am trying to start sonnar runner using command line, I get following error:

> Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft
>   Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Users\Administrator>cd..
>
> C:\Users>cd..
>
> C:>cd WIndows
>
> C:\Windows>d:
>
> D:>cd xampp
>
> D:\xampp>cd htdocs
>
> D:\xampp\htdocs>sonar-runner -e 'sonar-runner' is not recognized as an
>   internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Is this because I have project and sonnarqube on different drives? Please help.

Answer (score 4):

It's because the `sonar-runner` executable  is not in your current directory and Windows do not know where to find it. You need to add the directory containing `sonar-runner` to your `PATH` environment variable (see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program) for a similar case).

Note: SonarQube 4.5 is ancient, you should use the [latest 5.6 LTS](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/) instead.

Comment: thanks for replying. I added system variable and also appended in evvironment variable.  Here is my path variable now: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Skype\Phone;%SONAR_RUNNER_HOME%\bin

Comment: I had to download and setup sonar scanner , sonar runner was not working. After setting environment variable properly , all issues were resolved.

Comment: @Swati, do we need to use sonar scanner in order to make 'sonar-runner' working ?

Answer (score 2):

Go to this link
https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner/

download sonarscanner depends on your os,

then unzip it

C:\sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472-windows\bin\sonar-scanner.bat

add the path to environment variable