# 'npm-windows-upgrade' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, npm

I ran

```
$ npm install --global --production npm-windows-upgrade
```

and it returned this positive looking feedback

```
├── cli-spinner@0.2.5
├── commander@2.9.0 (graceful-readlink@1.0.1)
├── chalk@1.1.3 (ansi-styles@2.2.1, escape-string-regexp@1.0.5, supports-color@2
.0.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1, has-ansi@2.0.0)
├── promise@7.1.1 (asap@2.0.4)
├── inquirer@1.0.3 (ansi-escapes@1.4.0, mute-stream@0.0.6, through@2.3.8, cli-wi
dth@2.1.0, strip-ansi@3.0.1, figures@1.7.0, pinkie-promise@2.0.1, run-async@2.2.
0, string-width@1.0.1, cli-cursor@1.0.2, rx@4.1.0, lodash@4.14.0)
├── babel-polyfill@6.9.1 (regenerator-runtime@0.9.5, babel-runtime@6.9.2, core-j
s@2.4.1)
├── regenerator-runtime-only@0.8.38 (promise@6.1.0, es6-symbol@2.0.1)
└── prompt@1.0.0 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.4.0, colors@1.1.2, read@1.0.7, ut
ile@0.3.0, winston@2.1.1)
```

But when I run 
`$ npm-windows-upgrade`

I get

> '$ npm-windows-upgrade' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command

I was following the directions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-windows-upgrade). Any idea what's going on? I've been googling it for a while and not getting much more than those basic instructions.

**UPDATE**
Realized the issue was with everything I was trying to install globally. I thought the other packages I was trying to run worked but they did not. For example `$ webpack` returns the same error after installing it gloablly.

**BACKGROUND**

I'm running windows and had previously installed npm. When that started giving me all sorts of bugs I upgraded to npm3. I belive it was just

```
$ npm install npm3 -g
```

and then running all my commands starting with npm3, for example

```
$ npm3 install webpack --save
```

Today the same command gave me

> 'npm3' is not recognized as an internal or external command

So I tried to reinstall it with regular npm which gave me "'npm' ins not recognized..."

I was able to get npm working again after following [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28821955/2372289) lovely instructions, but cannot figure out how to get back to version 3.

Also `$ npm -v` right now is `2.15.1`

Answer (score 10):

To answer my own question.

The problem was my path settings. Npm itself was working, but for some reason the location where it was installing global node modules was in different directory. I saw this when I ran

`$ npm install npm-windows-upgrade -g`

The first few lines it prints when you install show where it is being installed.

I noticed it was being installed in

`C:\Users\(my_username)\AppData\Roaming\npm\nodemodules\npm-windows-upgrade`

even though I had just fixed npm by pointing it to

`C:\ProgramFiles\npm`

so I changed that to the npm location it was actually using to

`C:\Users\(my_username)\AppData\Roaming\npm`

restarted my computer and it worked.

[Here again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program/28821955#28821955) are instructions to change your path variables.

Comment: to get npm location use "npm config get prefix", this also works with similar problems with other packages: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56734369/10755097