# error in compile less with node.js in intelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, less

I installed node.js and I did all of settings that [JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/compiling-sass-less-and-scss-to-css.html) said.But I have this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5nmd.png)

What's the problem?

Comment: Have you installed node.js and added it to your PATH?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes i did in enviroment varibles

Answer (score 1):

You need to set node.js directory path so that intellij can recognize it as a command.

Please refer the answer to the following question.

['node' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file while using phonegap/cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program)

Thanks.