# Node executable not found while using node version manager for windows

Tags: node.js, nvm

For node version management in windows I have used [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows).

As per steps mentioned in documentation executed the following command,

To Install Node.js v8

```
nvm install 8.9.4
```

To use it as default version,

```
nvm use 8.9.4
```

After setting up nodejs v8 as default version, When i tried to verify the node js version using command **(node -v)**. Am getting error as **Node is not recognized as an internal or external command**

I didn't got any error while installing node, but "node" is not recognized.

**Note: Am running my command prompt as Adminstrator, NVM environment variables properties are,**

1. NVM_HOME - C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Roaming\nvm
2. NVM_SYMLINK - C:\Program Files\nodejs

> When I checked the folder **C:\Program Files\nodejs**, The folder is
>   empty, None of the node executable files was found.

Comment: are you working on a windows environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['node' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file while using phonegap/cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: Yes am working on windows environment. Environment variable is configured properly in my case. NVM_SYMLINK is mapped in to Path variable default by nvm-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type the below command in cmd to get version info

```
nvm list
```

Here is an perfect tutorial for you to run and see how nvm runs in cmd in windows.
https://medium.com/appseed-io/how-to-run-multiple-versions-of-node-js-with-nvm-for-windows-ffbe5c7a2b47

Comment: Thank you, In nvm settings.txt file, I have changed the node path from path: C:\Program Files\ nodejs to C:\nodejs. I worked like a charm, but i am not sure why nvm was not able to copy node.js settings inside Program Files.