# Getting "'node' is not recognized" error when running JavaScript with Code Runner in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

After I installed Code Runner in VS Code then used it to run my JS code, I'm getting this runtime error:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

What does that mean?

Comment: Maybe check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program

Answer (score 2):

What also helped me was (after installing node) going into `VS settings`, finding

```
code-runner.runInTerminal
```

and ticking it on.

Comment: It's not working for me. I think extra step is needed. It was giving the error: "node : The term 'node' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again."

Answer (score 1):

The error message means you have not installed Node.js on your machine. Make sure you have installed the Node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/, and set the correct `PATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

With the error during installation of node js make sure the add path is checked before installation. When the installation is done restart the vs code. It should be fine.