# Node.js - "node" command works, but not when through another framework

Tags: node.js, powershell, ionic-framework, gulp, nvm

I have Node.js + NPM installed; I can run `node -v` in my console and get back the current version.

I have also tried using NVM Windows as a Node.js version manager and can run both `node -v` and `npm -v` there as well.

HOWEVER, when trying to use another framework like Gulp or Ionic or whatever, I keep getting the error:

> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

`node` is obviously a cmdlet as I can run `node -v`.. but somehow my other frameworks are no longer able to find it.

Path is correct and everything looks good.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['node' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file while using phonegap/cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: I did check both of these (they are the same post).  It turns out it was just the ConEmu program's cmd/powershell manager that wasn't able to recognize the paths that deep or something.

I was able to run the commands successfully in CMD and Powershell stock and have now switched to 'cmder' which is also working.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The program `ConEmu` for windows terminal management wasn't pulling or allowing programs to access the paths through subcalls or something it seems.  I tested with `CMD` and `Powershell` respectively and both worked as expected.

I couldn't get `ConEmu` to seemingly pass these path to subroutines.. so I uninstalled it and found an alternative called `Cmder` that is built on `ConEmu` and it was able to pick them up just fine.

I don't know specifically if it was just a setting in `ConEmu` I couldn't find or if I needed to manually add these--but happy knowing `Cmder` just does it automatically.

Comment: @user2138520 Can you please be more specific how you solved this problem, because it seems that I have almost same situation.