# installed node.js successfully, but can't check it by cmd

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I installed node.js successfully, but can't check it by cmd: `node -v`

> -> 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['node' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file while using phonegap/cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program)

Answer (score -1):

try to type it in the cmd:
$ node --version

Answer (score -1):

full step to checking the node.

```
local@host:~$ node --version
v9.8.0
local@host:~$ npm -v
6.8.0
```

After this , create a js file (hello.js) and write below code on that file.

```
console.log("node is installed and running!");
```

Now run that file:

```
local@host:~$ node hello.js
node is installed and running!
```