# Problems installing Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I am having trouble installing Angular globally. I have included the error below.

```
C:\Users\DevSa\ng -> C:\Users\DevSa\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@8.3.19 postinstall C:\Users\DevSa\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.3.19 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.3.19 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DevSa\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-26T21_34_00_712Z-debug.log
```

Comment: did you install node.js? You may need to explain more about your setup

Comment: Yes I have installed node js and when running node -v I get v10.16.3.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program

Comment: I've already done this several times and it just won't solve the issue. Have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` at the top of your environment variables PATH list and then `C:\Users\{your username}\AppData\Roaming\npm` below it.

Hope solves your issue.