# npm install bcrypt failed node

Tags: node.js, npm, bcrypt

$ npm install bcrypt

> bcrypt@5.0.0 install D:\courses\Angela Yu - Web Development\31. Authentication & Security\Secrets - Starting Code\node_modules\bcrypt
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

The system cannot find the path specified.
'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm WARN website@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN website@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 9009
npm ERR! bcrypt@5.0.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 9009
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@5.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Aryan chauhan\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-07-15T16_53_36_616Z-debug.log

Comment: Assuming node.js is already installed,  you need to set node.js folder path into system variables or user variables.  Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem can be for two things, please check the following:

- Bcrypt 5 it's the newest version of this package, and this package have some issues with some node's versions, we can see this [here](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#version-compatibility). Although it does not show version 5, it is very recent and it is possible that it is not documented. Try to update the node version (I recommend to use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to achieve this or test your bcrypt in a testing project with a more recent node version.
- Node isn't recognized. Try to execute node in the terminal and see if you're entering in the REPL. If not, and an error message it's displayed, this can be a signal that you don't have nodejs. Again, I recommend use nvm to install it.