# NPX create-react-app terminal tells me node is not installed but it is

Tags: node.js

At the risk of looking like a complete idiot, why doesn't `npx create-react-app my-app` work for me? I have node and npm installed and updated, both in my path (as far as I can tell). When I type `node -v` and `npm -v` it works perfectly fine, gives me the version numbers, and I can use them just fine, but I get *'"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.* from the terminal when I try the create-react-app statement. Everything else I've found on the internet tries to say by adding it to the path it will work, but I must be missing something.

By the way, I'm using windows with GitBash.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not use if it is useful info to u or not, I see many windows user face issue with username which contains space, also check ur path to project whether it contains space or not

Comment: node works perfectly fine outside of npx, wouldn't that mean the path is correct? @vengleabso

Comment: No, it doesn't, node, npx, or npm which are installed in windows working fine, but some module which used by `create-react-app` does not properly check the path that contains spacing

Comment: So you are saying I need to adjust the path to be without spaces? Or just to make sure I have my spaces in the right places? Not following you here... @vengleabso

Answer (score 0):

**First step:**

`npm cache clean --force`

**Second step:**

`npm install -g create-react-app`

**Third step:**

Once installation successful, try running

`npx create-react-app my-app`

Comment: same thing happened, even after a successful global installation

Comment: Did you followed the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program) If not, can you have a look? Feels like something wrong with the Environment Variable Paths

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, I agree with you, it feels like a path thing but I cannot figure it out for the life of me...

Comment: can you give it a try using windows cmd or powershell?

Comment: Worked in command prompt... So I guess my issue is with git bash? how do I fix that haha

Comment: Try adding a slash after the path variable part, i.e. `C:\Program Files\nodejs\`

Comment: I think I got what you were saying, still didn't work from GitBash though...

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue and I am using hyper terminal instead of hyper I used windows PowerShell and it worked for me