# VS code error: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I want to setup javascript for VS code. I'm pretty sure that I've done all of the steps needed to setup that is:

1. Download javascript from the official website.
2. Download the neccessary extensions from VS code.

But when I try to run the code, the compiler gives me this error:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.091 seconds
```

I'm using Windows 10.

What's wrong?

Comment: I mean... have you installed [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)?

Comment: Of course. @Jake

Comment: Ok, just asking because you don't really "download javascript" and I didn't know what that meant

Comment: If you open up a new command prompt (`Windows + R, "cmd"`) and type `node --version`, what does it say?  And/or, where are you running your code that is throwing the error you're seeing (eg, are you in command prompt?  VSCode?  somewhere else?)

Comment: I think you can find the answer on this link. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program)

Comment: @Jake It does give me the current version `v19.8.0`