# Trying to read a json file

Tags: javascript, json

I want to read a json file but i have this issue: 'node' is not recognized as an internal or an external command, operable program or batch file

The js file

```
import { P1 } from './info.json'

console.log(P1)
```

The JSON file

```
{
    "P1" : {
        "x" : 0,
        "y" : 0,
        "life" : 3,
        "ang" : 0,
        "shoot" : false
    },
    
    "P2" : {
        "x" : 0,
        "y" : 0,
        "life" : 3,
        "ang" : 0,
        "shoot" : false
    }
}
```

I tried to use the answer in this article but nothing worked: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412938/node-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-an-external-command-operable-program"

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you have node installed?

Comment: If you are running in `node.js`, this can be done.  If you are running in a browser, then of course you don't have access to the server's file system at all.  You would need to do an AJAX request to fetch the contents.  That's not hard to do.

Comment: How do you fetch or install `node`? Technically it is possible to fetch the Node.js release archive, extract `node` to PATH, then run `node` directly. Then you can use import assertions to import JSON.